# How to make an optional include in a bottle template?

Tags: python, bottle

I would like to add an optional include in a bottle template.

Unfortunately this does not work as expected:

```py
<foo>

    % include(required_view)

    <%
        try:
            include(optional_view)
        except NameError:
            pass
    %>

</foo>
```

It does indeed make the optional import, but it stops after that.
(So `</foo>` is missing from the result.)

I would like to allow for the variable `optional_view` to be undefined.
Always adding `'optional_view': None` to the context would be annoying.
(Not to mention always adding an empty view.)

Comment: Did you try `{% include 'optional_view.j2' ignore missing %}`

Comment: I just tried it, but only the ignoring part works. It does not include anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end keyword was missing. This works:

```py
<foo>

    % include(required_view)

    <%
        try:
            include(optional_view)
        except NameError:
            pass
        end
    %>

</foo>
```

The right answer came from [this followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76934592).

Quote from the Bottle documentation about [embedded Python code](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#embedded-python-code):

> Note that `%` and `<% %>` work in exactly the same way. The latter is only a convenient way to type less and avoid clutter for longer code segments. This means that in `<% %>` blocks, all indented code must be terminated with an `end`.