# What does "finally: pass" do in Python? (e.g. in try – except – finally)

Tags: python, bottle, finally, try-finally

I would have assumed a `finally` clause with only a `pass` to be pointless.

But in a Bottle template, the following code for an optional include would not work without it.
The result would contain everything before, and the included code itself, but nothing after it.
(See the [corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891374).)

```py
try:
    include(optional_view)
except NameError:
    pass
finally:
    pass
```

What does `finally: pass` do, and when is it useful?

Comment: `pass` is essentially a placeholder for code in this case. In general it's a does nothing operation that is uses where an operation is required by the syntax.

Comment: The above two comments are what I would have intuitively said, but they don't account for the behaviour that OP observes in the linked question.  Wonder if Bottle is doing something special in parsing the template?

Comment: Are you sure that this piece of code is executed and not e.g. a monkey patched version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`finally: pass` does nothing, but you don't actually have `finally: pass`. You're writing a Bottle template, not Python, and you have broken Bottle template syntax.

Bottle templates [**ignore indentation**](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#embedded-python-code) in inline code, which means they need a different way to tell when a block statement ends. Bottle templates use a special `end` keyword for this. Your try-except needs an `end`:

```
try:
    whatever()
except NameError:
    pass
end
```

Otherwise, the `except` block continues, and stuff that wasn't supposed to go in the `except` is considered part of the `except`.

With `finally: pass`, the stuff that was incorrectly part of the `except` is now incorrectly part of the `finally`, so it runs in cases where it wouldn't have run as part of the `except`.

Comment: One easily forgets, that `<% code in tags %>` is not quite Python.

Answer (score 0):

The ‘finally’ keyword in Python is used to ensure that code within the “finally” block will always be executed, regardless of whether an exception occurs or not, where if an exception does occur within the “try” block, both the appropriate “except” and then finally blocks would execute; however, if no exceptions occurred only the finally block would run after completion of try.
So in that case, the except clause makes a difference, even though the pass statement itself is still just a placeholder.